# Shows only the last item in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, show-hide

I have a jQuery code as shown below.
I want to go through the whole arrays - show a message for 5 seconds and then go to the next and show it for 5 seconds, and on to the next.
The problem is that it shows only the last item - "Four".

```
  <script>
    $(function(){
      var myTab = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
      $(myTab).each(function(i, elem){
          $('#showHere').text(elem).fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
      })
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your loop ends long before the first animation is complete, and `.text()` doesn't wait for animations.

To fix it, get rid of the `.each()`, and use a callback to the `.fadeOut()` that manually increments a counter.

```
$(function(){
  var i = 0; // maintain a counter
  var myTab = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];

  // Create a `cycle` function (invoked immediately, see below)
  (function cycle() {
      // Only try the display if `i` is in the Array range
      if (i < myTab.length) {
          $('#showHere').text(myTab[i])
                        .fadeIn('slow')
                        .delay(5000)
                        .fadeOut('slow', cycle); // Pass `cycle` as a callback
          i++;
      }
  })(); // Invoke `cycle` immediately
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to grab a handle of the `div` element that you are calling multiple times for the sake of performance:

```
var showHere =  $('#showHere');
```

Then you want be using a `setTimeout` function:

```
 var myTab = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
 var showHere =  $('#showHere');
 $(myTab).each(function (i, elem) {
     setTimeout( function(){
             showHere.text(elem).fadeIn('slow').fadeOut('slow');
     }, i*2000);
 });
```

> Note that we multiply the `setTimeout` time by index, otherwise everything would be executed in the same time period.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/urahara/49ka7oph/1/

Comment: FYI, his delay should be after the `fadeIn` and before the `fadeOut`.